# Making label underline on mouse hover

Tags: c#, winforms, label, underline

I need to make label underline when I enter the label with my mouse. How can I do that? I tried few options but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? is this winforms, wpf or maybe something else?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that. I'm working on WinForms

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of your label to modify the `Font` used

```
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, label1.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Underline); 
}

private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, label1.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Regular); 
}
```

If you do not need to modify the font name or size you can directly use `new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline)`

Also, if you need to add multiple styles, you can use the `|` operator :

```
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, label1.Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events like so:

```
private void label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
}

private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this.
   set a new Instance of Font

```
private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 8, FontStyle.Underline);
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 8, FontStyle.Bold|FontStyle.Underline);//For Bold Also
        }   
private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font.Name, 8);
        }
```